# Layers not showing up in layers panel, but show in styling panel

Tags: qgis, layers

I have a QGIS project that has stopped showing the layers in the layers panel and the map, but they show up in the layer styling panel:

[image]

I have had this issue before, and reported it on the QGIS Users mailing list - but did not get any responses.

Here is the QGIS file here, with the user/passwords removed:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfdbe02drj3uaua/Layers_Not_Showing.qgs?dl=0

Can anyone spot anything in the file that might be corrupted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the element `<layer-tree-group>` (line 6) is empty, while it should contain the list of available layers. You can likely re-built it using the layer ID found in other parts of your qgs file + copy-paste from a valid (new) project.

Comment: I found the <layer-tree-group>, and tried to paste in the references to the layers that are missing, but the same behavior exists. I even tried opening this in QGIS 3.0 but with the same issue.