# Output of Processing Algorithm Doesn't Show Up in Layers Panel

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I'm writing a PyQGIS Processing plugin that takes a series of inputs and uses them to run other PyQGIS processing plugins that I wrote. The problem I'm having is that the layers my plugin returns don't show up in the layers panel, similar to [this guy's problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281431/layers-not-showing-up-in-layers-panel-but-show-in-styling-panel). How do I resolve this issue?

Here's my processAlgorithm method:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    #unpack parameters arguement

    pin_dropper_alg_params = {
        #like 20 input params
        QScoutPinDropperAlgorithm.DROPPED_PINS_OUTPUT: "memory:"  # I promise I read this somewhere
    }

    # this processing algorithm produces a vector layer of pin geometry type
    pin_drop_out = processing.run("QScout:droppins", pin_dropper_alg_params,
                                  context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    pin_drop_out = pin_drop_out[QScoutPinDropperAlgorithm.DROPPED_PINS_OUTPUT]

    vals_raster = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, QScoutValueGrabberAlgorithm.RASTER_INPUT, context)

    # VALUE GRABBER PARAMS
    grab_alg_params = {
        QScoutValueGrabberAlgorithm.RASTER_INPUT: vals_raster,
        QScoutValueGrabberAlgorithm.POINTS_INPUT: pin_drop_out,
        QScoutValueGrabberAlgorithm.POINTS_WITH_VALUES_OUTPUT: parameters[self.DROP_AND_GRAB_POINTS_OUT]
    }

    # this processing algorithm produces a vector layer of pin geometry type
    points_layer_id = processing.runAndLoadResults("QScout:valuegrab", grab_alg_params,
                                                context=context, feedback=feedback)
    points_layer_id = points_layer_id[QScoutValueGrabberAlgorithm.POINTS_WITH_VALUES_OUTPUT]
    points_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(points_layer_id)

    # GRID AGGREGATOR PARAMS
    grid_w = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, QScoutGridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_CELL_W_INPUT, context)
    grid_h = self.parameterAsDouble(parameters, QScoutGridAggregatorAlgorithm.GRID_CELL_H_INPUT, context)
    ag_idx = self.parameterAsEnum(parameters, QScoutGridAggregatorAlgorithm.AGGREGATION_FUNCTION_INPUT, context)

    # this is a bit wonky
    fields_to_use_list = map(lambda f: f.strip(), fields_to_use.split(","))
    ag_fields_list = points_layer.fields()
    regexes = "|".join(map(lambda r: "(%s)" % r, [ROW_REGEX, COL_REGEX, VINE_REGEX, PANEL_REGEX]))
    ag_fields_list = filter(lambda f:
                       (not fields_to_use or f.name() in fields_to_use_list)
                       and not re.match(regexes, f.name())
                       and (f.type() == QVariant.Int or f.type() == QVariant.Double),
                       ag_fields_list)
    ag_fields = ",".join(map(lambda f: f.name(), ag_fields_list))
    # for field in ag_fields_list:
    #     ag_fields.append(field)

    grid_ag_alg_params = {
        # some input params
        QScoutGridAggregatorAlgorithm.AGGREGATE_GRID_OUTPUT: parameters[self.DROP_AND_GRAB_GRID_OUT]
    }

    # this plugin produces a vector layer of polygon geometry type
    grid_alg_out = processing.runAndLoadResults("QScout:gridaggregator", grid_ag_alg_params,
                                                context=context, feedback=feedback)

    ag_layer_id = grid_alg_out[QScoutGridAggregatorAlgorithm.AGGREGATE_GRID_OUTPUT]

    return {self.DROP_AND_GRAB_POINTS_OUT: points_layer_id, self.DROP_AND_GRAB_GRID_OUT: ag_layer_id}
```

Comment: You can also take a look to this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345145/processing-script-returns-no-layer and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278406/getting-layertree-reference-in-processing-script-in-qgis-3

Comment: That was very helpful - thanks!